# Plotting horizontal and vertical lines

Tags: plotting, algebra

If I run:

```
Plot[y = 10, {x, -3, 5}]
```

output:

[image]

If I run:

```
Plot[x = 10, {y, -3, 5}]
```

I am getting exactly same output as in first case.

**I need:**

1. To plot  `y=10` and `x from -3 to 5`
2. To plot  `x=10` and `y from -3 to 5`

How can I do that and what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Plot shows a function independant from name. But you can add a line like:
'Show[Plot[y = 10, {x, -3, 5}], Graphics[Line[{{1, 0}, {1, 20}}]]]'

Answer (score 2):

You can draw lines directly with `Graphics`, and then show its axes:

```
Graphics[{Line[{{10, -3}, {10, 5}}], Line[{{-3, 10}, {5, 10}}]}, Axes -> True]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for exploring one more option.

```
Plot[10, {x, -3, 5}, GridLines -> {{10}, None}, PlotRange -> {{-3, 11}, {-3, 11}}, 
GridLinesStyle -> Directive[RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], AbsoluteThickness[1.6]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Show[
  Plot[10,{x,-3,5},PlotRange->{{-3,12},{-4,12}}],
  Graphics[Line[{{10,-3},{10,5}}]]
]
```

The `Plot` will give your horizontal line. If you don't give that a `PlotRange` then it will only show the diagram from x=-3 to x=5 and you want to have that plot large enough so that it will include your vertical line when x=10.

Then the `Graphics` will give your vertical line.

And the `Show` will combine both those.

As always there are several different ways, sometimes a dozen different ways, to accomplish anything in Mathematica. Pick one you can memorize and use without making too many mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

The form

```
Plot[f,{x,-3,5}]
```

plots `f` across the range `-3,5`. If `f` is a function of `x`, then it will plot `f[x]` but your expressions `y=10` and `x=10` aren't functions of `x`.  They're assignments to `y` and to `x`, respectively.  *Mathematica's* rather aggressive evaluator evaluates them both, returning `10` in both cases, and merrily plots

```
Plot[10,{x,-3,5}]
```

for you.  Try changing the assignment to `x` or to `y` and see what value the variable has after the `Plot` command.

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
Plot[10, {x, -3, 5}, PlotRange -> {{-3, 12}, {-4, 12}}, Epilog -> Line[{{10, -3}, {10, 5}}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

#### [`ParametricPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html)

```
ParametricPlot[{{x, 10}, {10, x}}, {x, -3, 5}]
```

[image]

Use many options to embellish:

```
p1 = ParametricPlot[{{x, 10}, {10, x}}, {x, -3, 5}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1], 
  FrameLabel -> {{"Y", None}, {"X", None}}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Y = 10", "X = 10"}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{-3, 0, 5, 10}, {-3, 0, 5, 10}}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], Thick, Arrowheads[{-.05, .05}]], 
  GridLines -> {{-3, 0, 5, 10}, {-3, 0, 5, 10}}]
```

[image]

```
  p1 /. Line -> Arrow
```

[image]